# Using reCaptcha

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to use reCaptcha on my project with JSF. Corresponding primefaces component doesn't want to work properly inside wizard component. I decided to try to use the code from example for JSP http://code.google.com/intl/en-en/apis/recaptcha/docs/java.html I can not understand how best to remake it to JSF. The problem is in java code injection into JSP and result validation via FacesValidator.

Can someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at tomahawk t:captcha on [MyFaces SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/tomahawk/trunk/core20/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/custom/captcha/). The code only use the standard JSF API (it was updated to use JSF 2.0 ResourceHandler API), so it can help you to build your own using recaptcha.